# My IBM X346 Series server is showing 5 HDD as DDD & only one HDD as Online....i have lot of files in HDD

Tags: ibm

There were all red in HDD Lights .. when we reinsert the raid controller show only one HDD online  other 5 HDD showing DDD in Bios features///

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually posted a question. But I'll go out on a limb and suggest that the correct answer to your unasked question is "restore from backups." If you don't have recoverable backups, you should do a few things:

1. Contact IBM support to see if anything can be done
2. If not, contact a data recovery service to get a quote. Then, determine if the value of the data is more than the price of recovery.
3. Implement a recoverable (ie tested frequently) backup process. No one cares about backups, but you've just learned that people do indeed care about restores.